# erlang method not called

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Hi I have a sample erlang code as,

```
%%file_comment
-module(helloworld).
%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([add/2,subtract/2,hello/0,greet_and_math/1]).
%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================
add(A,B)->
A+B.

subtract(A,B)->
io:format("SUBTRACT!~n"),
A-B.

hello()->
io:format("Hello, world!~n").

greet_and_math(X) ->
hello(),
subtract(X,3),
add(X,2).
```

And when I run

```
helloworld:greet_and_math(15).
```

Output is:

Hello, world!

SUBTRACT!

17

My doubt is why A-B which is 15-2=13 not printed on console?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you never *printed* 15-2. The code you need would look like this:

```
%%file_comment
-module(helloworld).
%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([add/2,subtract/2,hello/0,greet_and_math/1]).
%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================
add(A,B)->
A+B.

subtract(A,B)->
io:format("SUBTRACT!~n"),
io:format("~p~n", [A-B]).   % this will make sure A-B is printed to console

hello()->
io:format("Hello, world!~n").

greet_and_math(X) ->
hello(),
subtract(X,3),
add(X,2).
```

That will give you:

```
Hello, world!
SUBTRACT!
12
17
```

If you wonder why `17` is printed, that's because it is the last expression. This one is always printed to console after executing code because it is actually what is returned by your code. Just execute `io:format("hello~n").` on your console and you will see:

```
hello
ok
```

`ok` in this case is returned by `io:format`, and because it is the last expression, it will be printed.

```
io:format("hello~n"),
io:format("world~n").
```

will result in:

```
hello
world
ok
```

Only the last `ok` returned by the second `io:format` can be seen on console.
I hope you get the idea around how this works.

So in your case by typing:

```
4> A = helloworld:greet_and_math(15).
Hello, world!
SUBTRACT!
17
5> A.
17
6>
```

You see how `17` is the value returned by `greet_and_math(15)` because it is the last expression? And thus it can be assigned to a variable.

Comment: Yes. I am new to erlang so I was confused a bit. Now I understand that erlang returns the last expression executed, which is happening in the above case. Thanks

Comment: @Chakri if an answer answered your question you should mark it as accepted. Great answer btw.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

@a.w. it is not that the last value is automatically printed, it the *shell which prints the value* of the call you make. So when you call `greet_and_math(15)` the function will:

- Call `hello()` which prints the greeting. Its return value of `ok` from the call to `io:format` is ignored.
- Call `subtract(X, 3)`. Its return value of `12` is ignored.
- Call `add(X, 2)`. Its return value of `17` then becomes the return value of the whole function.

It is this return value of `17` which the **shell** prints out. So:

- Everything returns a value, you cannot not return a value.
- Returning a value and printing a value are very different things.

Comment: You are right! Of course it is not printed like using io:format. Sorry for not making this clearer. So as further addition, one might know that this value (17) is not seen on shell, when the caller is some other program which is not the shell. Then it is just returned to the caller, so it handle the returning value as desired. So thanks for adding this, hopefully it will help readers to understand even better what's happening.

Comment: @a.w. Yes, I have found that sometimes people do get confused about printing values and returning values, especially as the shell prints it for you.